# Named Entity Recognition for Tweets using R

Tags: r, twitter

My objective : I am trying to recognize the **location in a tweet**(if it exists).

I tried using the **Opennlp** package and ran into "**out of memory error**" several times in spite of increasing the heap memory size. 
The code terminates after identifying location for 6-8 tweets.

I am interested in only **100-150 locations(scope list)**, but matching each word in a tweet with the list for a collection of tweets is extremely inefficient.

I wanted to know if there are **any suitable packages** that can enable NER for twitter data using R besides 'NLP' ?

Also, what would be the **most efficient way to perform this routine** ?

I am **not very familiar** with python/Java hence would like to use R.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I sorted the out-of-memory issue.
I was importing the models repeatedly for each tweet. 
so I Commented that bit now..works fine.

Here is my code :

```
#Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7') # for 64-bit version\

#Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7') # for 32-bit version

#library(rJava)

#install.packages("openNLPmodels.en_1.5-1.tar.gz", repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at/", type = "source")

#library(openNLP)

#library(NLP)

#install en-ner-location.bin from http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/ and save in location given below



for(i in 1:nrow(quake1))

{

s<-quake1$text[i]

#sent_token_annotator <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()

#word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()

a2 <- annotate(s, list(sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))

#entity_annotator <- Maxent_Entity_Annotator(kind="location",language="en",model='C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.1.1\\library\\openNLP\\en-ner-location.bin')

a3<-entity_annotator(s, a2)

location<-""

if(length(a3)>0) {

for(j in 1:length(a3))

location<-paste(location,substring(s,a3$start[j],a3$end[j]),sep=";")

}

quake1$location[i]<-location

}
```

**New objective :** I want to ensure locations like #SanJose are also identified. Since most of hashtags w.r.t locations are single string.

Comment: Use a regex. will probably look something like "#[A-Za-z][a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]+)*"